# How to set such a progress bar and set it's progress in java

Tags: android

I am trying to set this progress bar not for a loading purpose .
Is there a way to set it's colors in xml and it's progress in java.
Finally thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: put your xml file

Comment: I haven't found any way to set the xml for that bar ,  for the icon and the text they are fine

Comment: so put your java code

Comment: I am in the search of how to get such element in java knowing it's id and set it's progres .

Answer (score 1):

Either you can use default progress bar like this

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/simpleProgressBar"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="0"
    android:indeterminateOnly="true" />
```

or there are few libs also https://github.com/DreaminginCodeZH/MaterialProgressBar you can try both and use.

and you can set progess with setProgress() method.

Sample complete code : - follow this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int progress = 0;
ProgressBar simpleProgressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // initiate progress bar and start button
    simpleProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.simpleProgressBar);
    Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    // perform click event on button
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // call a function
            setProgressValue(progress);

        }
    });
}

private void setProgressValue(final int progress) {

    // set the progress
    simpleProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
    // thread is used to change the progress value
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            setProgressValue(progress + 10);
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

**To Update the color of ProgressBar**

Create an xml file  in drawable -> custom_progress.xml

```
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#fff"
            android:startColor="#1f1"
            android:useLevel="true" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

then we need to add this into our progess bar like below and it will work: -

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/simpleProgressBar"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="0"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress" />
```

Comment: can't set the progress

Comment: check i added a complete working example class use this and try

Comment: is there a way to change the color?

Comment: yes , check the updated answer i added a custom drawable , follow the steps

Comment: I am not getting a fixed progress bar

Comment: code is working fine for ur question , why u downvoted